# Salesforce APEX: Test Class for a Run Batch

Tags: testing, batch-processing, apex

I have this class which is executing an APEX batch:

```
public class DeleteUtilizationDetailsRunBatch {
    @AuraEnabled
      public static void runBatch(Boolean isReport, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, String calType){
          DeleteUtilizationDetails b = new DeleteUtilizationDetails(isReport,startDate,endDate,calType);
      Database.executeBatch(b);
      }
  }
```

It's called from a component where the user enters the dates and pushes a button to run the job.  I've renamed the classes (for clarity) but now I need to be able to have a TEST class for this code above.  I haven't been able to find examples that meet this requirement but there has to be a way.  I can't deploy the class because it has 0% code coverage.
Thanks in advance

I haven't been able to deploy the class or find guidance/examples for a TEST class

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test class and call the batch directly in it,
first you need to initialize data in the test running context, after that you call the batch to manipulate this data , at the end you query on the database to do some assert.
lets assume that this batch work on the Account object and change the name to **account1**.

```
@isTest
private class DeleteUtilizationDetailsRunBatchTEST {
  static testmethod void caseCoverage() {
    Account a = new account(name='acc');
    insert a;
    Test.startTest();
    DeleteUtilizationDetails b = new DeleteUtilizationDetails(true,Date.newInstance(1,1,2023),true,Date.newInstance(1,1,2023),'CallType');
    Test.stopTest();
    Account a2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :a.Id]
    System.assertEquals('account1', a2.Name);
    Database.executeBatch(b);
   }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you! I'll try it out.